# Problems Restoring From Old Tapes with Bacula

Tags: bacula

I'm trying to restore an asterisk directory from an old tape.

In bacula, I unmount the current tape, take it out, stick the old tape in, mount LTO-2 and it gives this:
3001 Device "LTO-2" (/dev/nst0) is mounted with Volume "Default-3"

So it's already mounted. Now I restore by typing "restore", choose option 11 for restoring a directory, type in the job ID, then the directory, and it gives me this error:

No database record found for: /var/spool/asterisk/

Now I know what the error means, but what could cause that? Because I'm restoring from a full backup job, meaning the directory SHOULD be there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually check if the directory is indeed in the catalogue? In bconsole try something like `list files jobid=xxxx` and examine the output. If it's not there you may want to look into `bscan` in order to update the catalogue with the contents of that tape.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for the Original Poster, but for anyone else with this situation...

You need to bscan that tape in order to add it, and its contents back into the catalog. Once that is done, all the files on that tape will appear be  available for restoration.